# Background image load slowly in react native

Tags: react-native

I use an image for background like this

```
<Image
  source={Images.workingBg}
  style={styles.container}
>
  {this.renderHeader(navigation)}
  {this.renderContent(navigation)}
</Image>
```

But image display slowly, text show before and image show after that even though that image is loaded. 
[image]

Comment: How do you know the image is loaded? How long does it take to display it?

Comment: I'm sure the image is loaded, cause I load it async before. But when I login to, text always displays before image. It takes ~ 1 sec

Comment: I've posted the answer @Hoai Truong

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 16):

Because images in RN are **decoded natively in a separate thread**.

Image decoding can take more than a frame-worth of time. This is one of the major sources of **frame drops** on the web because decoding is done in the main thread.

So RN displaying the placeholder for a few more frames while it is decoding the images used in components, then show them at different times after each individual image has loaded (instead of waiting then show the whole component at once when it's ready).

See: [Off-thread Decoding](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#off-thread-decoding)

**Note**

Images are loaded **differently** in development/debugging and "real" production. During local debugging the images will be served over HTTP from the packager server, whereas in production they will be bundled with the app.

**Solution**

Try doing a [production build](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html) (full release build) on device to see if it's actually a problem or just a development mode side effect.

Or try the workaround from [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2570#issuecomment-244614564)

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.image = (<Image source={require('./background.png')} />);
}
```

and in your `render()` function:

```
render() {
    return(
        <View>
            {this.image}
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: I use this image for background image, so I cannot preload before like this. And in I loaded Async image before ```loadAssetsAsync = async() => {
    return Promise.all([
      Asset.loadAsync([
        Images.welcomeBg,
        Images.workingBg,
        Images.logo,
      ]),
      Font.loadAsync({
        'AvenirLTCom-Light': require('@assets/fonts/AvenirLTCom-Light.ttf'),
        'AvenirLTCom-Black': require('@assets/fonts/AvenirLTCom-Black.ttf'),
      })
    ])
  }
```

Comment: As I said before, this is default behaviour of RN. Did you try do a production build?

Comment: Yes, I try a product build, it the same. Images still display slowly. Maybe I'm not clear about image decoding. In fact, image is saved into the disk. But why it still display slower than text

Comment: well I try your solution @nhoxbypass, still doesn't work. I load the images on `componentWillMount` and pass them to a component which actually uses them, still experience image stuttering when loading